# What is an infinite gap minus another infinite gap?

Tags: calculus, infinity

I was asked this question on a quiz I received a few days ago and I was kind of confused on what the answer would be. Here it is,

> Set up and find the area between $$f(x)=x^2-x$$ and $$g(x)=x-1$$

So here is what I did to solve it,

Intersection at x=1 so,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{1} ((x^2-x)-(x-1)) dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} ((x-1)-(x^2+x))dx$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{1} (x^2-2x+1) dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} (-x^2-1)dx$$
$$ \tfrac{x^3}{3}-x^2 +x \Big|_{-\infty}^1 + \tfrac{-x^3}{3} -x \Big|_1^\infty$$

At this point, I became very confused so I wrote this down,
$$0$$

Anyway, my teacher gave me credit for the problem but I was wondering, is zero correct?

Comment: $-x - x = -2x$ in the first integral. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Maffred Now I understand a question mark near that:/

Comment: The region was improperly specified.

Comment: @AndréNicolas region was improperly specified? - I just edited the question is that answers your comment

Comment: I suggest to rewrite the first with $-x$ and take a single limit to $+\infty$

Comment: If you think the first like a parabola and the second like a line, of course the area between them is $+\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that yes, $0$ is correct. These two lines only intersect in one point, and so, based on the usual meaning of "between" I would say either the area between the curves is infinite, or zero. Both seem pretty reasonable conclusions, and it just depends on what one considers inside vs outside. I think that since in most cases we are assuming that the area is not infinite (our justification for taking the inside area between $x^2$ and $x+1$), zero is the better answer.

I wouldn't say $+\infty$ was wrong though. The integral you are trying to calculate comes out to $+\infty$), and that's also a valid answer to the question. I assume the teacher made a mistake while making the problem, because it doesn't properly specify the region unambiguously.

Comment: If you solve the integral it is $+\infty$ if I don't go wrong!

Comment: Oh well if you mean the area "between" it is 0 since the line is tangent. By the way the question is not very clear!

Comment: The integral posted in the problem evaluates to $+\infty$. I think that it's the wrong integral to calculate though, and $\int_1^1 (x-1)-(x^2-x)dx=0$. I think both are valid answers but that $0$ is a better answer.